# Smooth Scroll doesn't work when I set the html and body height to 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
   position: relative;
}

#home {
   height: 100%;
   background: url("../img/test.jpg") center no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

I'm using the Smooth Scroll JavaScript from CSS-Tricks

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

The first section of the page it's a full page image, so I need the html and body to have a height of 100% to set the #home height to 100% too but for some reason when I do this the Smooth Scroll effect doesn't work and when I remove the height: 100% from html and body it does work.

Anyone with the same problem?

Comment: If body is 100 % height, it should not have any scroll so probably if there is your in undefined territory and lots of effects might break.

Comment: Do you know how to make the body the size of the content but still make the #home div 100%?

Comment: Sorry, Its been a long time since I worked on the GUI part of our apps, now a days I work almost exclusively back end and services.

Answer (score 2):

Use **min-height: 100%** instead of **height: 100%**.

Answer (score 0):

This might help. Very useful link.

http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/quick-guide-adding-smooth-scrolling-to-your-webpages/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.